# How do I backup files using LFTP from the remote server to the local

Tags: server, ftp, webserver

What command would I use in the terminal to backup files onto the server? I already have the LFTP installed.

Comment: you mean lftp as ftp client? where you've installed it, on your client or on the server? You want to backup the server and store the files on your client or want to backup the client and store the files on the server?

Comment: I have websites on godaddy's dedicated server and I want to download those websites periodical into a folder on the ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

on your server (there the original files you want to backup are) you need a ftp server running, then you can just type:
lftp sftp://user:password@host  -e "get remote-file.name; bye"
(see [get a file to or from a remote server via command line or script](http://docs.salixos.org/wiki/How_to_send/get_a_file_to/from_a_remote_server_via_command_line_or_script) on your client (on which you installed lftp)....

Comment: So I tried this and it says "access failed: no such file" I used ls I saw the file there but I want to download the entire directory not just a file.

Comment: Also, where is this command sending my file. Don't I have to lcd first?

Comment: thanks though this helped I was missing quotation marks and to get the directory its: mirror "public_html"